# MySQL Trigger: After restart present?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I wanted to know if I restart my server/or the database, do I lost then my MySQL Triggers or will they be still available after the restart or shutdown? Or must I add them every time then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless they're set on a memory table (can they be? not even sure), then they'll still be there. Barring a catastrophic crash, it would be a very poor database if it "forgot" things between invocations.

Comment: Triggers are stored with the rest of the database metadata - they'll be preserved across restarts. The exception is memory tables, which are designed to NOT persist.